# C# submit a POST form and retrieve the GET result

Tags: c#, html, post, get, request

I've seen several posts speaking of this but can't manage to get a working solution...

So basically I want to login to a website by submitting the POST html form then (using the session cookie I guess) retrieve the GET result content once I'm logged in.

To prepare this I used WireShark to sniff the activity and sure enough I find the POST request with the form in index.php info then the GET request in user.php

So to reproduce this in C# :

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("xxx/index.php");
var postData = "login_name=xxx";
postData += "&login_pw=xxx";
postData += "&login_submit=Connexion";
postData += "&login_server=1";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

First problem is that in WireShqrk when I get to the GET request I see a cookie but in C# in the response the cookies list is empty

I still try to get the resulting content :

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("xxx/user.php");
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

But this response is basically the html code for the original login page.

There you go, any advice will be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: So what differences do you see between the original request and the one performed by your code? Is there some difference in the headers? Or maybe the body?

Comment: indeed if I compare both POST requests the one from firefox is length 500 while the one from my C# code is 134. I'm comparing the headers but pretty sure got all them down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was to not allow auto redirect and get the cookie info from

```
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `CookieContainer` on the request, and share that container on subsequent requests.

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("xxx/index.php");
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
//do the post...

var getRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("xxx/index.php");
getRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
//do the get...
```

Comment: ok but in thqt case i get an exception on the POST request / too many automatic redirection tentatives (translated from french). The status is Protocol Error and the Stack is at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: That is something that you'll need to trace out. Maybe the result of that Post is a 301 to a location that will also 301 and so on....

Comment: ok and how can I do that trace ? if there is a redirection shouldn't I see it in WireShark ? Addingly the ACK from the POST request is coming from the same destination IP address

Comment: a 301 redirect can be for the same server. you need to decode the http response data and headers not only the TCP.

Comment: another interesting thing when I compare the GetRequestStream.Write with that of firefox is that in my C# code the cookiecontainer is empty but in the POST method from firefox i have a cookie, any idea why that is ?